# Symfony Entity Annotation Assert One of Two must be not null

Tags: symfony, annotations, entity, assert

Do someone know how to do that in entity by asserts?

IF email and number IS EMPTY THEN return error => 'one of two fields must be not empty'
ELSE THEN valid by other asserts

Code:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", nullable=true, type="string")
 * @Assert\Email(
 *     message = "The email '{{ value }}' is not a valid email.",
 *     checkMX = true
 * )
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="phone", nullable=true, type="string")
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *      "/48[0-9]{9}/", message="Wrong number format"
 * )
 */
private $phone;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
 * @Assert\Expression(
 *     "!this.getEmail() && !this.getPhone()",
 *     message="Please, enter email or phone."
 * )
 */
class Entity
{
    // ...
}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html

Comment: That's cool! Thank You :)  But good way is after little modification :
 * @Assert\Expression(
 *     "this.getEmail() or this.getPhone()",
 *     message="is_empty.email_and_phone"
 * )

Answer (score 1):

This is an exemple of using a method that verify the condition on the field:

```
/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @Solr\Field(type="boolean")
 * @ORM\Column(name="professionel", type="boolean")
 */
private $professionel;

/**
 * @Assert\IsTrue(message = "Type d'actualité invalide")
 */
public function isValidprofessionel()
{
    if (!$this->professionel && !$this->particulier) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a custom validator for the whole class. Here's a symfony tutorial.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html